# How/Why does Phil Coulson's prosthetic arm work around Remoraths?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In ***Season 5 Episode 19 : Option Two***, the Remoraths are introduced. According to Deke,

> **Deke**: The Remoraths are marauders. They're intergalactic scavengers with no planet of their own, so they just take from others, and and wherever they go, darkness follows.
>
> **Fitz**: Darkness? That's a little vague.
>
> **Deke**: Well, it's not the concept of darkness, it's literal darkness.

Later, in the episode, Fitz claims that the **Remoraths possess some sort of EMP that render all electronic devices** (*such as icers, walkies etc.*) **useless**. And it is shown across Episode 19 through 22 how Remorath's presence affects electronics.

However in ***Episode 21: The Force of Gravity***, in at least two instances, (listed below) Coulson's prosthetic electronic arm seems to work just fine around the Remorath warriors.

1. *When Coulson uses his prosthetic arm's scanner to find a weakness in the cell walls* and,
2. *When he creates a shield to protect himself and May from the shooting Remorath*

How was Coulson's arm able to function normally around the electronics-blocking Remoraths?

Answer (score 3):

At the times mentioned, they were on the Remoraths' ship. The ship's lights and systems appeared to be working fine. From this, the guess would be that the Remoraths' can turn this effect off, and do so when on their own ship.

I don't remember if Coulson was in the Lighthouse when the Remoraths first attacked.

Comment: Is there any evidence that the Remoraths can turn off their ability? For now, I'm okay with wiki entries too.

Comment: @Shreedhar - Is there a reason to believe that their ships are somehow immune to the emp effect? Either a) the ship functions of something other than electronics; b) the ship's electronics are hardened such that the effect doesn't affect them; or c) the emp effect can be turned off. If the effect is artificially generated, then the third option is the most logical one.